# How can I recreate these Apple device shadows?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shadows, apple

Looking to re-create these shadows on devices (not limited to phones / tablets). Looks like stacked drop shadows, but the fall-off around the whole shadow and hard edge to blurred edge on the corner is proving difficult.

https://www.apple.com/ca/ios/ios-13/

Please see image below. I’m using Photoshop. Have tried stacking drop shadows, but the bottom left corner and falloff of shadows seems difficult to mimic.

[image]

Comment: Hey ShadowHelp. You'd likely get a quicker answer if you edited your question to include what you've tried and what's not working about your approach. As it is, your question looks like a low-effort question and may be ignored. Additionally, clarifying what program you're using would be very helpful. Also, which shadows are you talking about? A screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: Paste an example using the forum tool, do not paste an everchanging link.

Comment: It is difficult because it is a 3D render! These shadows are more complex to mimic in 2D. Show us your image so we can help you better solve where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I recreate those type of shadows constantly at my work.

**Tool used:** Photoshop

## My process consists of three main layers:

1. A soft darker and shorter layer around the object with a little bit of distance.
2. A softer lighter and longer shadow growing in the opposite angle with the light source
3. A even softer, very light and very spreaded shadow following shadow number 2

## Pictures

1. **Shadow 1** (added via Drop Shadow)

[image: Shadow 1 (added via Drop Shadow)]

2. **Shadow 2 part 1** - at a 45 degree angle, created via pen tool

[image: Shadow 2 part 1 - at a 45 degree angle]

3. **Shadow 2 part 2** - diffuse using eraser, gaussian blur and lower opacity. 
   [image: Shadow 2 part 2 - diffus using eraser, gaussian blur and lower opacity.]
4. **Shadow 3 part 1** - at a 50 degree angle, created via pen tool
   [image: Shadow 3 part 1 - at a 50 degree angle, created via pen tool]
5. **Shadow 3 part 2** - diffuse just like shadow 2, but increase blur and lower opacity even more
   [image: Shadow 3 part 2 - diffuse just like shadow 2, but increase blur and lower opacity even more]

### Conclusion

I created this blue object with it's shadow in 5-10 minutes. The more time you put into your shadow the greater result it has.
*Real life example:* The shadow of these objects below were created using this technique by me:
[image]

Comment: Hello. Can you explain what the long flat shadow is for? How it is used in the composition?

Comment: @LeoNas It is the basic shape used in the composition, then you start diffusing it. 
Create a flat black shape, considering light angle and object size. Then start using the eraser tool (0% hardness, 20% opacity, 40% flow) and work its diffusion (if you do not know where to diffuse, grab some example images of a similar object with a similar shadow on the internet. Practice and reference are key). You can use gaussian blur to help on the diffusion process.

Comment: Ok. I got it now.